# Fast identifier generating method using hashing

Tags: java, hash

I want to create a unique identifier for a document using its 'name' and 'version' in java. When the 'name' and 'version' are given as inputs, the identifier has to be generated and on the other hand there should be able to get back 'name' and 'version' from the identifier of a document also. Can I use hashing for this requirement? If so what would be the fastest hashing algorithm.

Comment: What is `version`? An `int`?

Comment: Your identifier could be `name_version`

Comment: You can simply concatenate your IDs. BTW, hashing IS NOT the right way to get an ID, since you can have collisions. Moreover, with a good hash function, you shouldn't be able to get the original content back. That's one of the purpose of cryptographic hashing

Comment: How is this different to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030498/generating-unique-identifier-using-two-strings

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hashing alone, because you can't recover the name and version back from the hash.

Do you have any other requirements, like can the name and version be recovered from the identifier without a decryption key. If you don't have any other requirements you could just concatenate the name and version together to form your unique id.